# Getting Continuous Markov Chain Solution from the Discrete Solution

Tags: statistics, continuity, markov-chains, markov-process

If I have the transition probabilities matrix, $P_{ij}$, for the discrete case, it is possible to find the continuous case time-dependant transition probabilities matrix, $P_{ij}(t)$?

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a discrete time Markov Chain, you account with the information about *where* the chain jumps. This information is given by the transition probability matrix $P$.

On the other hand, if you have a continuous time Markov chain, you account with the information about *where* the chain jumps **and** *when* it jumps. This information is completely given by the infinitesimal matrix $Q$, defined by 
$$q_{ij}=\begin{cases}-\mu_i,&i=j,\\\mu_ip_{ij},&i\neq j,
\end{cases}$$ 
where $\mu_1,\mu_2,...$ are the rates of the exponential distributions associated with the times of permanences in each estate.

So you can dirive the continuous tieme Markov chain **only if** you have the parameters $\mu_1,\mu_2,...$ (and the probabilities $p_{ij}$ given by $P$). Once you have the matrix $Q$, use the equation $P(t)=\exp\{tQ\}$.

Comment: This is the basic relationship between Q and P(t), I don't have a way to solve this equation. It generates overflows etc. I am trying to go from P in the discrete to P(t) in the continuous, not from Q.

Comment: My idea is to go from P (and the exponential rates) to Q, and then to P(t) using that basic relation. But if you do not have the exponential rates you just can't go from P to P(t). As I said, you need the information about "when" the chain jumps.